# How to poke connectionString in sqlmap.config?

Tags: asp.net, xml, nant, ibatis

In a similar way to what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885957/how-to-change-connection-string-automatically-on-build-with-nant), I would like to xmlpoke connectionString from an sqlmap.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<sqlMapConfig
   xmlns="http://ibatis.apache.org/dataMapper"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

    <database>
        <provider name="oracleClient1.0"/>
        <dataSource name="DSExtranetAdherent"
                    connectionString="Data Source=MyInstance;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPwd;Unicode=True;"/>

    </database>

</sqlMapConfig>
```

I tried with this poke:

```
<xmlpoke
  file="${ConfigPath}\sqlmap.config"
  xpath="/sqlMapConfig/database/dataSource/@connectionString"
  value="${ConnectionString}" />
```

But I get an error message:

> [xmlpoke] No matching nodes were found with XPath expression '/sqlMapConfig/database/dataSource/@connectionString'.

The xpath is effective when I remove the `xmlns` property, but then I get this runtime error:

> Unable to load file via resource "SqlMap.config" as resource.

Any idea on how to fix this xmlpoke with a good xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlns` is the default namespace, xmlpoke require a prefix for xpath parsing:

```
<xmlpoke
  file="${ConfigPath}\sqlmap.config"
  xpath="/iba:sqlMapConfig/iba:database/iba:dataSource/@connectionString"
  value="${ConnectionString}">
  <namespaces>
    <namespace prefix="iba" uri="http://ibatis.apache.org/dataMapper" />
  </namespaces>
</xmlpoke>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `<namespaces>` child node for the `<xmlpoke>` task:

```
<namespaces>
    <namespace prefix="xsi" uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
</namespaces>
```

The [last sample on this page](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html) explains just your case.

Comment: As the problem seems to appear with `xmlns` attribute which has no prefix, adding this namespace is inefficient.  Adding `<namespace prefix="" uri="http://ibatis.apache.org/dataMapper" />` is not more efficient.